# SQL Join - некорректно заданное имя поля?

Tags: sql, join, group-by

Схема БД состоит из четырех таблиц:

`Product(maker, model, type)`

`PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)`

`Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, price, screen)`

`Printer(code, model, color, type, price)`

Таблица Product представляет производителя (maker), номер модели (model) и тип ('PC' - ПК, 'Laptop' - ПК-блокнот или 'Printer' - принтер). В таблице PC для каждого ПК, однозначно определяемого уникальным кодом – code, указаны модель – model (внешний ключ к таблице Product), скорость - speed (процессора в мегагерцах), объем памяти - ram (в мегабайтах), размер диска - hd (в гигабайтах), скорость считывающего устройства - cd (например, '4x') и цена - price. Таблица Laptop аналогична таблице РС за исключением того, что вместо скорости CD содержит размер экрана -screen (в дюймах). В таблице Printer для каждой модели принтера указывается, является ли он цветным - color ('y', если цветной), тип принтера - type (лазерный – 'Laser', струйный – 'Jet' или матричный – 'Matrix') и цена - price.

Нужно найти производителей, выпускающих по меньшей мере три различных модели ПК.

Есть простое решение, которое корректно работает:

```
SELECT maker, COUNT(DISTINCT model) 
FROM product 
WHERE type='pc' 
GROUP BY maker 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model)>=3
```

Интересует, почему не работает решение с JOIN?

```
SELECT maker, COUNT(DISTINCT model) 
FROM product JOIN pc 
ON product.model=pc.model 
GROUP BY maker 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model)>=3
```

Интерпретатор языка SQL, представленный на одном популярном сайте выдает следующую ошибку:

> Ambiguous column name 'model'.

Как следует исправить запрос?

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть `model` в таблице `product` и в таблице `pc` - парсер элементарно не понимает, какое из двух полей вы имеете в виду. Парсеры в СУБД обычно довольно глупые, потому что должны быть быстрые - им некогда догадываться, что раз у вас связь по этому полю и сделана - то оба `model` заведомо равны и не имеет значения, к какому из двух обращаться.

Поэтому в общем случае для запросов из нескольких таблиц лучше использовать обращения по `имя_таблицы.имя_колонки`. Это длиннее и дольше пишется, но не будет смущать ни парсер запроса ни других читающих ваш код людей - становится понятнее, что из какой таблицы вы получаете.

---

Впрочем, большинство реализаций позволяют написать условие `using` вместо `on`:

```
SELECT maker, COUNT(DISTINCT model) 
FROM product JOIN pc 
USING(model)
GROUP BY maker 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT model)>=3
```

Что как раз обозначает равенство по одноимённому в обеих таблицах полю. И этот вариант парсеры обычно воспринимают как единое поле model и не смущаются при обращении к нему.

Comment: Ваш вариант запроса с USING интерпретатор также не принимает:
`"model" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.`

Comment: значит ваша реализация не понимает. Вы же не писали, какая у вас СУБД

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь объединить таблицы в которых присутствуют поля с одинаковыми именами. Если вы пытаетесь использовать данные имена в списке полей для выборки или условиях/группировках, интерпретатор не знает из какой таблицы брать данные и поэтому показывает ошибку "Ambiguous column name 'model'."
Для того, что бы этого не происходило, указывайте имя таблицы перед именем поля. Вот пример с вашим запросом:

```
SELECT maker, COUNT(DISTINCT product.model) 
FROM product JOIN pc 
ON product.model=pc.model 
GROUP BY maker 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product.model)>=3
```

Comment: ваш запрос выдает некорректный результат. сообщение с сайта: `Неверно. * Неверное число записей (меньше на 1)`

Comment: PS "интерпретатор не знает из какой таблицы брать данные" наверное, из той, которая получилась после операции JOIN? JOIN-то я корректно и однозначно задал, а where, group by, select уже потом выполняются и применяются именно к той таблице, которая получилась после джойна. а в ней только одно поле `model`

Comment: `получилась после джойна. а в ней только одно поле model` - неа, их два.

Comment: Дмитрий, подскажите, какую бд вы используете? Синтаксис может отличаться.

Comment: "В настоящее время на рейтинговых этапах мы используем Microsoft SQL Server 2017, а на обучающем этапе - дополнительно MariaDB-10.2.13 (совместима с MySQL 8), PostgreSQL 10.3 и Oracle Database 11g."
Данный вопрос взят из обучающего этапа

Comment: Синтаксически запрос верен, попробуйте перечитать задачу. Судя по всему вам нужно другое условие, возможно COUNT(DISTINCT pc.code)>= 3 или что-то еще. Так же почитайте документацию по JOIN в SQL, вам стоит разобраться, что получается в результате.